# Edit random videos from youtube using ffmpeg

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to edit several videos of different size, format, ratio, etc (random videos from youtube)

As to edit these I use : `ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -s 1280x720 -c copy output/edited_video.mp4` All videos are listed in videos.txt

But it doesn't work like that, it seems ffmpeg need homogeneous videos to edit the finale video. For now the first video is displayed fine but the following are glitched...

**How can I homogenize any video to the same size, ratio, format, codec, ...?**

(For now I use: `ffmpeg -i input/video.mp4 -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 -s 1280x720 -c copy temp/video.mp4` but it seems it's not enough.)

Comment: Given it looks like you will need to re-encode the videos anyway, it might be easier to do something based on extracting each frame from the videos in turn, and then encoding that image sequence.

Comment: Yep it might be a solution, I'll try this.